# Proving that $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(y_k)}{x_k-y_k}=f'(c)$ where $\lim_{k\to \infty}x_k=\lim_{k\to \infty}y_k=c$ with $x_k<c<y_k$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Question.

Suppose that a function $f$ is defined on an interval $I$, $c$ is a point of $I$, and {$x_k$} and {$y_k$} are any two sequences in $I$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty}x_k=\lim_{k\to \infty}y_k=c$ with $x_k<c<y_k$ for all $k$. Prove that, if $f'(c)$ exists, then $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(y_k)}{x_k-y_k}=f'(c).$

My Attempt.

Let $\epsilon_k=\frac{1}{k}$ be given.

For $\epsilon_1=1,$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $x_1,y_1\in I, x_1,y_1\in N'(c;\delta_1)$ implies $\vert \frac{f(x_1)-f(y_1)}{x_1-y_1} -f'(c) \vert<\epsilon_1.$

For $\epsilon_2=\frac{1}{2},$ there exists $0<\delta_2<$min$\{\vert x_1-c \vert,\vert y_1-c \vert,\epsilon_2\}$ such that $x_2,y_2\in I, x_2,y_2\in N'(c;\delta_2)$ implies $\vert \frac{f(x_2)-f(y_2)}{x_2-y_2} -f'(c) \vert<\epsilon_2.$

Similarly, for $\epsilon_{k}=\frac{1}{k},$ there exists $0<\delta_k<$min$\{\vert x_{k-1}-c \vert,\vert y_{k-1}-c \vert,\epsilon_k\}$ such that $x_k,y_k\in I, x_k,y_k\in N'(c;\delta_k)$ implies $\vert \frac{f(x_k)-f(y_k)}{x_k-y_k} -f'(c) \vert<\epsilon_k.$

Then by taking the limit to infinity, we obtain $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(y_k)}{x_k-y_k}=f'(c).$

It really took me a lot of time to finish the proof and I need this to be checked by an expert:) Is the proof okay? Any response would be appreciated!

Comment: The existence of each $\delta_k$ comes out from nowhere. For example, why do you think $\delta_1$ exists with the property in your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first phrase "For $\epsilon_1=1$, there exists $\delta_1$ such that [...] $|\frac{f(x_1)-f(y_1)}{x_1-y_1}-f'(c)|<\epsilon_1$" is already not ok, because that is essentially what you want to prove. You are not using the definition of $f'(c)$.

You should do something like this: Given $\epsilon$, suppose $x,y$ are sufficiently close to $c$ (so that $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c)\pm\epsilon$ and similarly for $y$) with $x<c<y$. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}&=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{c-y}\frac{c-y}{x-y}\\
&=(f'(c)\pm\epsilon)\frac{x-c}{x-y}+(f'(c)\pm\epsilon)\frac{c-y}{x-y}\\
&=f'(c)\pm\epsilon
\end{align*}