# Proving that $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(c)}{x_k-c}=f'(c)$ where $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k =c $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Question.

Suppose that a function $f$ is defined on an interval $I$, $c$ is a point of $I$, and $\{x_k\}$ is any sequence of points in $I$, no term of which is $c$, such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k =c $. Define a sequence $\{y_k\}$ by $y_k=\frac{f(x_k)-f(c)}{x_k-c}$.

a)Prove that $f'(c)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{k\to \infty} y_k $ exists and has the same value for every such sequence $\{x_k\}$.

b)Prove that, if $f'(c)$ exists, then $\lim_{k\to \infty} y_k=f'(c) $ for every such sequence $\{x_k\}$.

My attempt(...?)

a) Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Since $f'(c)$ exists, $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} $ exists.

(...)

There exists $k_0\in \mathbb N$ such that for $k\ge k_0$, $\vert \frac{f(x_k)-f(c)}{x_k-c}-L \vert< \epsilon$.

How can I find the link between $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ and $\frac{f(x_k)-f(c)}{x_k-c}$?

It just seems so trivial to me and I cannot fill the blank.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: also, why not use this almost identical question you posted yesterday: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928128/proving-that-lim-k-to-infty-fracfx-k-fy-kx-k-y-k-fc-where-lim?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)$ is equivalent to for every sequence $x_{k}\rightarrow c$ , $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f(x_k)=f(c)$

Comment: Did you mean $\lim f(x) = f(c)$?

Comment: @Alex sure did :(. Thank you

Comment: @qbert Isn't it trivial? Do I have to prove the equivalence?

Comment: @Chloe if that is trivial, then so is this

Comment: @Chloe another hint, defining a clever auxiliary function could be a neat and elegant way to prove this quickly

Comment: @qbert hmmmm.... still not so sure about this. Let me sleep on it. Anyway, thanks for your help!